# Overwrite function of existing object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider following code:

```
mynamespace.myclass = function() {
    this.myfunction = function() { alert("Original"); }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to overwrite myfunction from outside of mynamespace.myclass declaration.

While adding new functions through prototype seems to work ok, if I define a function with the same name the original function doesn't get overwritten:

```
mynamespace.myclass.prototype.myfunction = function() { 
   alert("Overwritten");
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because `myfunction` is being added in the constructor, which happens *after* the prototype properties are added (so that the "Original" is in fact overwriting the "Overwritten").

You'll have to mimic this behaviour, by overwriting `mynamespace.myclass` itself:

```
var oldClass = mynamespace.myclass; // Copy original before overwriting
mynamespace.myclass = function () {
    // Apply the original constructor on this object
    oldClass.apply(this, arguments);

    // Now overwrite the target function after construction
    this.myfunction = function () { alert("Overwritten"); };
};
mynamespace.prototype = oldClass.prototype; // Same prototype
```