# why I can't "overwrite" a method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, overriding

I would like to override a function of a JS object by adding it to its prototype.

```
var originalObject = function(){
    this.someFun = function(){
        // ...
    }
}

var otherObj = function(){
    this.otherFun = function(){
        originalObject.prototype.fun =  function(){
            return 'This is the overwritten function.';
        }
        var o = new originalObject();
        return o.fun()
    }
}
```

This way when I execute `new otherObj().otherFun()` I have the expected result (***'This is the overwritten function.'***), but if the function I'm trying to add is already part of `originalObject`

```
var originalObject = function(){
    this.fun = function(){
        return 'This is the original function';
    }
    this.someFun = function(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then the result is not the expected one, infact `new otherObj().otherFun()` returns ***'This is the original function'***.

so, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6885525/2689638) the only way to add the method to the prototype and override it? And most important why I can't "overwrite" the function in the prototype?

Comment: Try to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933288/overwrite-function-of-existing-object-in-javascript

Comment: I suppose inheritance goes from parents to children. If you have two functions, one in the prototype and another in an object which inherits from it, the function in the object (the child) overrides the one in the prototype. 
So: you are overriding the function in the prototype, but not in the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In js objects there are two levels which are depend on directly object and depend on directly prototype. And when you call a property which is in object, it starts to search from the root then looks in branches. You can see the tree belowed picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the function already existed in object, it will be called out instead of being looked for in objects prototype.